# Linux modify cshrc file for path above prompt

Tags: linux

I would like some help to set up my .cshrc to display my current path above my prompt every time I a new prompt displays.

Terminal Example:

```
/current/directory/path
username@machinename > enter cmd prompt

/current/directory/path
username@machinename > display whatever return
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using tcsh, the following should work:

```
set prompt = "%~\n%n@%m > "
```

Brief explanation:

- `%~` shows the current directory, using "~" for home;
- `\n` moves to the next line;
- `%n` is the user name;
- `%m` is the host name up to the first dot.

For more information, refer to the manual page for tcsh(1), section "Special shell variables".

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you very much for your help and the explanation.